# Hadoop cluster and client connection

Tags: hadoop, hive, client, apache-pig, cluster-computing

I have the hadoop cluster. Now i want to install the pig and hive on another machines as a client. The client machine will not be a part of that cluster so is it possible? if possible then how i connect that client machine with cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, If you have Hadoop cluster then you must have Master node(Namenode) + Slave node(DataNode)

The one another thing is **Client node**.
The working of Hadoop cluster is:
[image: Hadoop Cluster]

Here Namenode and Datanode forms Hadoop Cluster, Client submits job to Namenode.

To achieve this, Client should have same copy of Hadoop Distribution and configuration which is present at Namenode.
Then Only Client will come to know on which node Job tracker is running, and IP of Namenode to access HDFS data.

Go to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314130/hadoop-client-and-cluster-separation/35321361)  [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252349/hadoop-client-node-configuration) for client configuration.

**According to your question**

After complete Hadoop cluster configuration(Master+slave+client). You need to do following steps :

1. Install Hive and Pig on Master Node
2. Install Hive and Pig on Client Node
3. Now Start Coding pig/hive on client node.

Feel free to comment if doubt....!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ankur. I have another doubt. If i have to R tool with Hadoop  Cluster so what i have to do?

Comment: If you got answer to above question. Mark as correct Answer.

Comment: You need to install RHadoop on your cluster for connecting R tool with Hadoop cluster.

Comment: I will give you more descriptive answer if you ask another question related to R connect with Hadoop.

Comment: Sure Mr. Ankur right now i am focusing to learn the Hadoop as well as R programming. While time of actual implementation I will definitely ask you about it as i think i have to suffer a lot.

Comment: Ok I will help you.